# Convert video with vp9 codec using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-codecs

I am trying to convert `input.mp4` video to `output.mkv` using vp9 codec.
I have install development version of ffmpeg via: `brew install ffmpeg --devel`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec vp9 output.mkv
```

But I am getting error: `Unknown encoder 'vp9'` even the vp9 is included: `ffmpeg -codecs`

Comment: `brew install ffmpeg --with-libvpx --with-opus`

Comment: @JoelPurra `Usage: brew install [options] formula|cask [...]` `Error: invalid option: --with-libvpx`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most basic command is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus output.webm
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: VP9](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, but command do not work. Here is the log:
https://gist.github.com/pavelbinar/8236408

The problem probably is the fact that I do not have vp9 encoder installed/included (I thought that it in the ffmpeg 2.x)
https://gist.github.com/pavelbinar/8236426

Comment: I installed ffmpeg and all its components via this guide and it works now! https://sites.google.com/a/webmproject.org/wiki/ffmpeg/building-with-libvpx

Comment: How do I check if the input file has VP9 or some other codec?

Answer (score 3):

With my version of ffmpeg,

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 2.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
```

the command looks like this

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2000k -pass 1 -an -f webm /dev/null
ffmpeg    -i input.mkv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2000k -pass 2 -c:a opus -b:a 64k -f webm output.webm
```

i.e.

- leave out the experimental flags
- do a two pass encoding, because the first two seconds of the output are blurry otherwise. Doing a two pass encoding is also faster than single pass.
- when doing 2 pass, you do not need to encode the audio in the first pass as @FrankGalligan noted in a comment

Single pass is/was broken, according to http://wiki.webmproject.org/vp9/known-issues

Comment: Do not set `-strict experimental`. That was for older FFmpeg. When doing 2 pass, you do not need to encode the audio in the first pass. `ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2000k -pass 1 -an -f webm /dev/null` `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2000k -pass 2 -c:a opus -b:a 64k -f webm output.webm`

Comment: Its odd no one uses cq.  What is your reason to use webm vs mkv?